# Can I use NPM on a project created with Yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

The project was created and used with Yarn. Can you clone it and use it with NPM without any problems and without installing Yarn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple. I assume you have your project code with you. If it was create with yarn, there will be a `yarn.lock` file.

Delete the file and run `npm install`. It shall be up and running without issues.

Comment: But what about the fact that NPM will get different versions of the node modules than the ones that the rest of the team is working? Won't this cause problems down the line?

Comment: You can still install the exact version from the `package.json` file using this flag `--save-exact`.

I think it should work.